# How to override Log4j properties with a Java "-D..." command line argument?

Tags: java, log4j

Let's say you have a log4j2.xml configuration file of the following kind:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration...>
  <Properties>
     <Property name="appendToLogFile">false</Property>
  </Properties>

  <Appenders>
    ...
    <File name="File" filename="app.log" append="${appendToLogFile}">
      ...
    </File>
    ...
  </Appenders>
  ...
</Configuration>
```

How is it possible when you call your Java app in command line to override this `appendToLogFile` property by java command line argument `-Dwhatever.log4j.whatever.appendToLogFile=true` (I think I've read it somewhere that this is possible.
Alternative proposals that do something similar are also welcome of course (but I only want to have ONE log4j config file).
TYVMIA